# Concat pickle files

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter, pickle

I have two pickle files, the first is 5.6GB, the second 2.7GB. Inside they are dictionaries with the structure `{'204747-44' : {data}}`.

I just need to concatenate them, not by key. However, with this solution, my jupyter lab kernel dies, due to memory overflow.

Can you please tell me how to fix this? I would appreciate it!

I load them first with pandas with `pd.read_pickle()` and then do `dict1.update(dict2)`.

Comment: Not trying to be funny … getting more memory to support the dataset seems to be the logical answer.  Otherwise, can the data types be converted to a type which requires less memory?  (E.g.: `float64 -> float16`)

Comment: If you can read at least each file separately you could try to convert it in a different format like an Sqlite database, merge the databases and maybe convert them to another format finally.

Comment: `concatenate` is a specific `numpy` operation.  `pandas` may have some similar operations.  It is not a well defined term of python `list` or `dict`.  As you try `dict` does have an `update`.  Have you tried loading with the `pickle` module rather than `pandas`?  I don't know if `pandas` is adding to the memory use.  I haven't used it, but I assume `pd.read_pickle` produces a dataframe, not a `dict`.